# Debugging disabled Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFvPM.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upqRG.jpg) Debug option is disabled (hidden, cannot be turned on).

I tried searching in solution explorer, or delete Visual Studio and download it again, but it did not work.

Knowing that I am still a beginner in Visual Studio

Comment: Do you have a project open?

Comment: Do you have a startup project set? If it still doesn't work after setting it, please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

If the debug option is disabled or hidden in Visual Studio, there could be several reasons for this.

**Check Project Type**: Ensure that you are working on a project that supports debugging, such as a Console Application, Windows Forms Application, or a Class Library. If you are working on a project that does not support debugging (e.g., ASP.NET Web Forms or a Deployment project), the debug option may be disabled.

**Configuration Manager**: Make sure the project's configuration is set to "Debug" mode. To do this, go to the "Build" menu and select "Configuration Manager." In the Configuration Manager dialog, ensure that the "Active Solution Configuration" is set to "Debug."

**Check Toolbar and Menu**: The debug option can be toggled on and off in the toolbar or menu. Look for the "Debug" menu item in the top menu bar. If it's missing, try customizing the toolbar to add the "Debug" button back.

**Resetting Window Layout**: Sometimes, the Visual Studio window layout can get corrupted, which may hide certain options. You can try resetting the window layout to default settings by going to "Window" > "Reset Window Layout."

**Keyboard Shortcuts**: Ensure that you haven't accidentally changed or overridden the keyboard shortcuts for debugging. The default shortcut for starting debugging is typically F5 (for "Start Debugging").

**Repair Visual Studio**: If none of the above solutions work, there may be an issue with the Visual Studio installation. You can try repairing Visual Studio to see if that resolves the problem.

***Note*** :
It's important to note that deleting and re-downloading Visual Studio is not a recommended solution for resolving such issues. Reinstalling the application might not fix the underlying problem and could lead to additional complications.

Hope one of options will help to fix your issue.